# How to sum values in array by specific object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an array of js objects which look like this:

```
var objArr = [
     {"Country": "US", "City": "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "US", "City": "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "CN", "City": "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"},
     {"Country": "CN", "City": "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}
   ]
```

I wanna create a new array where the country is unique, but also the dates should be summed.

```
{"Country": "US", "2017-07-12":  "3", "2017-07-13": "4"},
{"Country": "CN", "2017-07-12": "10", "2017-07-13": "14"}
            ^^^^                ^^^^                ^^^^
```

I have problems getting my head around it.
Do I have to filter first, reduce it somehow, remap it,... I've no idea to start?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Oh, in that case you just need to group the entries by country and then sum the values of the same properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: In particular, you can have a look at [Scott Sauyet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484332/3689450) which provides a more flexible approach. Some others also show how you can group and transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `forEach` for array and go over each object date keys using `forEach` and build the one `res` object with unique keys as `Country` and accumulated values.
Use `Object.values` of res to get the array from res object.

Update: Fix to make sure always one type for dates which is `number`.

```js
var objArr = [
  { Country: "US", City: "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2" },
  { Country: "US", City: "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2" },
  { Country: "CN", City: "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" },
  { Country: "CN", City: "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" }
];

const update = data => {
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(({ Country, City, ...dates }) => {
    const item = res[Country] || { Country };
    Object.keys(dates).forEach(date => {
      item[date] = (item[date] || 0) + Number(dates[date]);
    });
    res[Country] = { ...item };
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

console.log(update(objArr));
```

Comment: im some of my results the values are strings, and some are integers. Is this normal? `
Country: "China"
3/1/20: 79826
3/2/20: 80026
1:
Country: "Thailand"
1/22/20: "2"
1/23/20: "3"

Comment: @Jan, Oh I see. I think its better to have same type for items. Here I think number is better. I updated answer to make sure always have number.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.reduce`, check if an object with the current country exists, if it does, loop through the `Object.keys` to update the values, if not, push a new one :

**EDIT** : If you don't want City you can destructure it `{City, ...curr}`

```js
var objArr = [
  { Country: "US", City: "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2" },
  { Country: "US", City: "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2" },
  { Country: "CN", City: "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" },
  { Country: "CN", City: "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7" }
];

var result = objArr.reduce((acc, {City, ...curr}) => {
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.Country === curr.Country);
  if (ndx > -1) {
    const [country, ...keys] = Object.keys(curr);
    keys.forEach(k => {
      acc[ndx][k] = +acc[ndx][k] + +curr[k];
    });
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Op don't want city in result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to create an object to group elements and then use `Object.values`

```js
var objArr = [
     {"Country": "US", "City": "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "1", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "US", "City": "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "2", "2017-07-13": "2"},
     {"Country": "CN", "City": "MyCity1", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"},
     {"Country": "CN", "City": "MyCity2", "2017-07-12": "5", "2017-07-13": "7"}
   ]

let keys = ["2017-07-12", "2017-07-13"];
const res = Object.values(objArr.reduce((ac, a) => {
  if(!ac[a.Country]){
    ac[a.Country] = {Country: a.Country};
  }

  keys.forEach(k => {
    ac[a.Country][k] = (ac[a.Country][k] || 0) + Number(a[k]);
  })
  return ac;
}, {}))
console.log(res)
```